# TeXShop saves file before I even click typeset. Any way to fix this?

Tags: texshop, mac

Like the title says, TeXShop will save any changes I make before I click typeset.  I haven't had this problem before. Any way to fix this?

Comment: See [TeXShop's auto save feature](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/aboutTeXShopAndLion2.html) - it saves automatically every few minutes.

Comment: @Werner How do I turn it off?

Comment: From the terminal, write `defaults write TeXShop AutoSaveEnabled NO`. Let me know if this works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Mac OS X preferences are managed through easily accessible control panels, but going behind the scenes with `defaults write` commands can lead to some genuinely useful tweaks that can only be made through the command line.

TeXShop has an auto-save feature that is on by default. However, there is no easy way to turn this off, except from the Terminal (in the `/Applications/Utilities/` directory) using `default write`.

[Changes to TeXShop 3.19, 3.20, 3.21](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/changes_3.html) reports:

> TeXShop now has a hidden command to turn off AutoSaving:
>
> ```
> defaults write TeXShop AutoSaveEnabled NO
> ```
>
> WARNING: This command will cause crashes on Lion, so it should only be used on Mountain Lion and above. The TeXShop developers use AutoSave. If you turn off AutoSave, you are entering untested waters.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues.  Autosave happens while editing a file, then cursor ends up at the end of my document.  The "undo" command doesn't work.  For me the editor became useless.

Turning this "feature" off, or having some control over this behaviour would be nice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/219063)